# How can nginx ensure that there is no garbled and interleaved log in the file of error.log?

Tags: nginx

As we known, nginx is multi processer model, is there garbled and interleaved problem in this kind of model. all worker process write log in same file of error.log and access.log

How is the logging performance of nginx log model under high concurrency and access connection? Relying on file locks?

want to understand the working principle of nginx log module in the case of high concurrency and access conneciont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NGINX log module doesn't rely on file locks. However, all worker processes will use the same file handle obtained by the master process once.

When entries do not exceed 512 bytes (typical atomic write size limit on many systems), which is the case with the standard access log format, writing to log files will be an atomic operation and no interleaving will happen.

If the access log format is heavily customized to include many details, and there are unusually long URLs, interleaving is theoretically possible.